# Adding numbering/label of fullcite entries in text?

Tags: citing

I've discovered `biblatex` and it's great. Specially for the `\fullcite` option which is exactly what I want (in order to add the full citation in the text and not wait for the bibliography section).

However I was wondering if it is possible to add the numbering as well. For all intents and purposes I wish to have the same type of entry we would have in the bibliography section but in the text using a `\fullcite` type command.

```
\fullcite{toto}
```

should provide

> [1] toto el al,  'writen by toto'

At the moment it only produces

> toto el al,  'writen by toto'

Comment: It would be good for you to include a minimum working example so that the solution can be sure to work with all of your options.  See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3301/47522.

Comment: Also note, you can use backticks `` and 4-space indentation to give code formatting in your question, as I have done in my edit.

Comment: thanks for the reformatting of the question. Apologies it was my first interaction with this board.

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you have to redeclare the `\fullcite` command to include the prefix and labelnumber fields.

A full example would be:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
   {{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% New
        \printfield{prefixnumber}% New
        \printfield{labelnumber}}} % New
  \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}

To learn more about \LaTeX, check out 
\fullcite{companion}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This appears as:

[image: example]

Note that the specifics could change depending on the particular options that you have loaded for your own document.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks a lot. It is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: @pablo If this solves your problem, feel free to mark it as an accepted answer by choosing the checkmark at the left. This helps to keep the site tidy.

Comment: Hello, if I use `biber` and  `xelatex`, how should I do this?