# How to reproduce a biblio reference in a text exactly as it appears in the reference section

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have a document with bibliographical references at the end handled by biblatex and biber.

I need to reproduce in the core of a text a bibliographical reference exactly in the same way as it appears in the bibliographical references.

I thought of a way to handling this issue by calling successively

```
\noindent \autocite{a} \Citeauthor{a}. \citetitle{a}.
```

However, I don't have a commande for `\cite-journalname` and another for `\cite-doi` or even `\cite-volume` or `\cite-pages`, ... So my solution does not work.

Any hint?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{a,
  date =     {2003},
  author =   {Author, Amy},
  title =    {Paper title},
  journaltitle = {Journal title},
  volume =   10,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {100-141},
  doi={10.1109/TAC.2016.2614910} 
  }  
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \section{My text}
    I need to print here a complete biblio reference exactly as it appears in the References section. A trial was to cite the reference in the following way:

    \noindent \autocite{a} \Citeauthor{a}. \citetitle{a}.

\section{References}
    \subsection{Journals}
    \newrefcontext[labelprefix=\Alph{subsection}-]
    \printbibliography[]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\fullcite{sigfridsson}`? That omits the label. If you need it, a more sophisticated solution is needed.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176260/35864 help?

Comment: Thanks a lot @moewe. The combination: \cite{a} \fullcite{a} allows to get the desired output.

Comment: But in that case the linked solution that combines the two into one command is preferable.

Answer (score -1):

The best is to ask bibLaTeX to do it for you.

Add after your `bibresource` some way to identify your "example" reference:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=doi,
            match=10.1109/TAC.2016.2614910,
            final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=example]
    }
  }
}
```

And then at desired spot:

```
\printbibliography[heading=none,keyword=example]
```

Comment: Thanks @Joce. The problem with your solution is that the exact reference number is not reproduced. Instead of [A-1], I only get [1].

Comment: You need to add the same option `labelprefix=\Alph{subsection}-` as in your MWE if you want the same formatting of the label.

Comment: Well, this seems not to be working. Since you were going for an ad-hoc solution in your MWE, you probably don't need to have this prefix automatically updated. Then you can insert `\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A-]` just above the new `\printbibliography` command.

Comment: My MWE is very short. In my whole biblio (more than 100 references), I do need the prefix to be updated in the way I defined it (in terms of subsections).

Comment: The downvote is surprising, given that the answer does provide a valid and complete solution - although in comments the OP requested a yet better one.

Comment: The solution you proposed does not give the correct citation reference. The exact solution is given by @moewe: the paper has to be cited (instead of printed again using \printbibliography). The combination: \cite{a} \fullcite{a} or the more sophisticated solution : tex.stackexchange.com/q/176260/35864         answers my question.

Comment: This doesn't quite justify a downvote, but you do what you like of course. Trying to be helpful doesn't mean to have the best solution of all at once.