# supercite and footnote

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I use a `\newcommand` combining `supercite` and `footfullcite` to have a bibliography reference in footnote and the same in the bibliography. I can't merge the numbers of the citation.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}    
\usepackage[autopunct=true,giveninits=true,autocite=superscript,backend=bibtex,sorting=none, sortlocale=auto,notetype=foot+end,style=numeric-comp,maxnames=10,maxbibnames=100,doi=true, isbn=true,url=false,eprint=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand{\PresCite}[1]{\autocite{#1} \footfullcite{#1}}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, frenchlinks=true, linkcolor=black,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=blue, citecolor=gray]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

bla bla bla \PresCite{Toto1900,Toto1901,Toto1902}

\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

The result is:

1. in text

   [image]
2. in footnote

   [image]
3. in bibliography

   [image]

What I would like:

1. in text

   [image]
2. in footnote

   [image]
3. in Bibliography

   [image]

Comment: no one could help?

Comment: I hope that someone can be help to you. I have a put a bounty for you.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: If I had been able to help you I would have done it with pleasure.

Comment: Clarification question: what do you want to do with regular footnotes? Duplicate the numbers, i.e., `\PresCite{abc,xyz} some text\footnote{footnote here}` produces footnotes _1. citation here [next line] 2. citation here [next line] 1. footnote here_? Or maybe make the footnote citations different, i.e., _[1] citation here [next line] [2] citation here [next line] 1. footnote here_? Or you are not planning to use regular footnotes at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the footnote marker is already provided by `\autocite`, a possible solution is to avoid `\footfullcite` and instead use a footnote without a marker, and use `\fullcite` inside that footnote. A footnote without a marker can be made following for example [Supressing the footnote number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250221/supressing-the-footnote-number), which creates a `hyperref` warning about an empty anchor, which can be suppressed following [avoiding hyperref warning: Ignoring empty anchor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415625/avoiding-hyperref-warning-ignoring-empty-anchor).

Normally `\fullcite` does not print the cite label (similar to `\footfullcite`) but you can add the number by redefining the `\fullcite` command as in [Adding numbering/label of fullcite entries in text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176260/adding-numbering-label-of-fullcite-entries-in-text). In the code below instead of redefining `\fullcite` a new macro `\myfullcite` is created so you can still use the original `\fullcite` in other places.

The redefinition of the macro also allows you to insert newlines after each citation in case of multiple citations, to simulate the appearance of multiple footnotes.

All that is left is some spacing issues in making the bibliography entries align in the footnote (with eachother and with regular footnotes). The first entry can be corrected with a negative `-1em` at the start of the footnote, while other lines can be corrected with negative space inside of `\myfullcite`.

Putting everything together:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[height=5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}    
\usepackage[autopunct=true,giveninits=true,autocite=superscript,backend=bibtex,sorting=none, sortlocale=auto,notetype=foot+end,style=numeric-comp,maxnames=10,maxbibnames=100,doi=true, isbn=true,url=false,eprint=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\addbibresource{library.bib} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
   {{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% New
        \printfield{prefixnumber}% New
        \printfield{labelnumber}}} % New
  \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\par\hspace{-1em}}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newcommand{\PresCite}[1]{%
\autocite{#1}%
\begin{NoHyper}%
\blfootnote{\hspace{-1em}\myfullcite{#1}}%
\end{NoHyper}
}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, frenchlinks=true, linkcolor=black,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=blue, citecolor=gray]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
regular cite \cite{Toto1899}

bla bla bla \PresCite{Toto1900,Toto1901,Toto1902}
normal\footnote{normal footnote} footnotes\footnote{second footnote}

just one \PresCite{Toto1899}

and again \PresCite{Toto1899}

\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

Result (page size reduced to 5cm with `geometry` for the screenshot):

[image]

Note that the citations are printed as `[1]` etc. and not as `1.`, to differentiate them from normal footnotes. If you don't want this then you can do the redefinition as follows:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myfullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
   {{   \printfield{prefixnumber}% New
        \printfield{labelnumber}.} % New
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\par\hspace{-0.85em}}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Note the slightly reduced negative space of `0.85em` instead of `1em`.

[image]

Note also that repeated `\PresCite` commands for the same reference create repeated footnotes, with the same number, as this number is taken from the reference list and not from the footnote counter as in `\footfullcite`.

---

Alternatively, if you just want compressed footnotes and it is not a prerequisite that the numbers must correspond to the bibliography numbering, then you can use the `footnoterange` package (see [Compressing consecutive footnote marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44165/compressing-consecutive-footnote-marks)) and create the (range of) footnotes inside of `\DeclareCiteCommand` by including the `footnoterange` environment in the pre- and post-code of the cite command and the `\footnote` commands in the loopcode (see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) of BibLaTeX on page 180).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[height=5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}    
\usepackage[autopunct=true,giveninits=true,autocite=superscript,backend=bibtex,sorting=none, sortlocale=auto,notetype=foot+end,style=numeric-comp,maxnames=10,maxbibnames=100,doi=true, isbn=true,url=false,eprint=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{footnoterange}
\addbibresource{library.bib} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\PresCite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}\begin{footnoterange}}
   {\footnote{\usedriver{\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}\end{footnoterange}}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, frenchlinks=true, linkcolor=black,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=blue, citecolor=gray]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
regular cite \cite{Toto1899}

bla bla bla \PresCite{Toto1900,Toto1901,Toto1902}normal\footnote{normal footnote} footnotes\footnote{second footnote}
\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: With all my heart I thank you very much to have help the user.